# React router after adding createBrowserHistory, the app is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used the version 1-rc for react router. My route config is something like below:

```jsx
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={About} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />         
    <Route path="user" component={User} />       
  </Route>
</Router>
```

And the access url is like below:
http://localhost:3001/assets# (entry point)
http://localhost:3001/assets#/about?_k=3mr0ay

However, when I added the createBrowserHistory support to the Route:

```jsx
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <Route path="assets/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={About} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />         
    <Route path="user" component={User} />       
  </Route>
</Router>
```

The app is not working correctly.

The error is:

> Warning: Location "/assets" did not match any routes

Even I add the /assets to the path it is still not working.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things which are new in RC1, one of them is that the [History](https://github.com/rackt/history) is now separated into another repo, so you no longer `import` it from React Router itself. Instead you use the [`History`](https://github.com/rackt/history). So you need to `npm install history`.

Also make sure that you remove your `node_modules` and install them again when migrating to 1.0.0-rc1:

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

I just put the example for you:

```jsx
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to='/'>Main</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class Contact extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Contact</div>;
  }
}

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <div>About</div> );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Home</div>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <Navigation />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
        <Route path='/' component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path='about' component={About} />
          <Route path='contact' component={Contact} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

More can be found in the React Router [documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/docs) and [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually I already got above working and it's no problem. The problem is the entry point for the path is not '/', it's '/assets'.

Comment: Definitely no. Your example is very basic one and I already got it working. But for my question, the root url is different. See the example above please.

Comment: the reason is not working for you is because you are adding extra `/` in the end of your path. then the URL you enter should be ending with this extra slash: `http://localhost:3001/assets/`. If you don't want it then your path should look like: `/assets` instead of `assets/`