# React-router 1.0.2 is not working after configure with History module 1.13.1

Tags: react-router

I'm experiencing this issue after configure `history` module with my sample application [here](https://github.com/milankarunarathne/phr-dashboard/tree/history-issue).

I tried to follow this pattern in react-router docs [Navigating Outside of Components](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md), and implemented it in

Create [`history.js`](https://github.com/milankarunarathne/phr-dashboard/blob/history-issue/login/config/history.js)

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Configure with [router](https://github.com/milankarunarathne/phr-dashboard/blob/history-issue/login/Login.js#L19)

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

import history from './config/history';
import routes from './config/routes';

let el = document.getElementById('login');
render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, el);
```

Trying to use [here](https://github.com/milankarunarathne/phr-dashboard/blob/history-issue/login/actions/SignUpActions.js#L14)

```
import history from '../config/history';
```

I'm using [webpack](https://github.com/milankarunarathne/phr-dashboard/blob/history-issue/webpack.config.js) and you can build it using `npm run webpack`, then server files with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`.
After that, when I want to go to `http://localhost:8080/public/login.html#/setup`, it's giving following error.

`Warning: Location "/public/login.html#/setup?_k=rnwzln" did not match any routes`

**If I removed `history={history}` in [`Login.js`](https://github.com/milankarunarathne/phr-dashboard/blob/history-issue/login/Login.js#L19), it works perfectly**

Can you help me to get through this? Is it a bug in react-router?

P.S.: I have looked into this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816678/react-router-after-adding-createbrowserhistory-the-app-is-not-working-as-expect), but it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a browserHistory and expecting hash urls to match.

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md

Comment: +1, @rpflo thanks for the help!. That's the cases. I just trying to flow an example, which is not my use cases. As it mentioned in the above docs, react-router is using hash history as default, and will be able to access it from child compenents via `this.props.history`. Thus changing route can be done by `this.props.history.pushState(null, '/new');`